# Teradata Counting specific records and total records

Tags: sql, teradata

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDb6h.png) : I have the following table from which I want to query certain records having certain conditions. I want to query the count of PO_Num's having Len x Wdth x ht < 16 x 16 x 24. Along with that, I also want another column for total PO nums.

The result I want is something that should look like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKOvf.png)

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results *in the question* would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `conditional aggregation`. I am not too familiar with `teradata` but you're using "len" as column name and it's a reserved keyword in some databases. Make sure it doesn't cause you issues down the road.

```
select count(*) as count1, 
       sum(case when wt > 15 and ht > 16 and len > 17 then 1 else 0 end) as count2
from yourtable;
```

Comment: I am using Teradata to write this query and looks like I cannot use it the way you have mentioned.

Comment: @amateur_yogi321 Interesting..this is supposed to be standard SQL. What error does it throw?

Comment: This is perfectly valid Standard & Teradata SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c1, c2 from
(Select count(*) as c1 from yourtable where wt > 15 and ht > 16 and len > 17 ) as count1,

(Select count(*) as c2 from yourtable) as total
```

Comment: Thanks Tarik! But I also want the total PO count along with the criteria I mentioned. Can I use a join or union to do that?

Comment: You need to use two subqueries. I will correct my response with an approximate answer.